# In a compact subset of a metric space, given an open cover. (test prep)

Tags: analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and suppose that $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ is an open cover of $\Omega$.  Prove that there exists a $\delta$ such that, for every $\omega \in \Omega$, there exists a $U_{\omega} \in U$ such that $B(\omega, \delta) \subseteq U_{\omega}$.  NOTE:  $\delta$ must be independent of $\omega$.

I can do this when either $\delta$ depends on $\omega$ or if $U$ is not given arbitrarily, but both of those conditions placed on the problem at once, has me at a crossroads.

Comment: That is [Lebesgue's number lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_number)

Answer (score 0):

... and the proof is not hard.

y assumption, for each $\omega \in \Omega$ there exists some $U_\omega$ with $\omega\in U_\omega$. As $U_\omega$ is open, we find some $\delta_\omega>0$ with $B(\omega,2\delta_\omega)\subseteq U_\omega$. The balls $B(\omega,\delta_\omega)$ cover $\Omega$. By compactness, a finite subcover suffices. Let $\delta$ be the minimum of the finally many $\delta_\omega$ of the subcover. Then for $\omega\in \Omega$, there is some $\omega'$ with $\omega\in B(\omega',\delta_{\omega'})$. Then $B(\omega,\delta)\subseteq B(\omega',2\delta_{\omega'})\subseteq U_{\omega'}$